# Can I use another _.get as the default for lodash _.get?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, key, lodash, default

d = {color:"red",height:"5",age:"200",shape:"square"}

given a dictionary, I can get a value with Lodash's _.get like so:

```
var myval = _.get(d, "height",null);
```

But, can I set the default to another _.get?
Like this:

```
var myval = _.get(d, "length",_.get(d, "height",null));
```

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: yes you can : )

Comment: did you try this before asking? Just wondering as you have the solution in the question itself ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
d = { color: "red", height: "5", age: "200", shape: "square" }
// Object { color: "red", height: "5", age: "200", shape: "square" }

_.get(d, 'hello', _.get(d, 'height', null));
// "5"
```